# Using jQuery to Select a DIV that exists only on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a couple of `div` that do not exist until the user places his mouse over some `img` which causes the `div` to popup, done via Google Maps API. How can I use jQuery to select this div when it is created (pops up on screen)?

**Current Code:**

```
$(function() {
    var height = $("#infobox_content").height();
    $("#infobox").css('height', height);
```

});

This does not work because the div does not exist yet.

---

**UPDATE**

---

**PHP Code that creates the DIV that popsup when Mouseover the Google Map Marker**
Note that every set of `<div>` created has the same id `infobox`, `infobox_content`. I can add a number to make them unique but then I will need to change my CSS stylesheet to select `infobox1, infobox2, infobox3.... infobox10`

```
foreach($config['markers'] as $marker) {
            $marker_number++;

            $map_JS .= '
            var boxText = document.createElement("div");
            boxText.style.cssText = "";
            boxText.innerHTML = "<div id=\'infobox\'> \
                                    <div id=\'infobox_content\'> \
                                        <strong>'.$marker['name'].'</strong><br /> \
                                        <p class=\'infobox_content\'> \
                                            143 1st St<br> \
                                            Cambridge MA 021232 \
                                    </div> \
                                </div>";

            var myOptions = {
                 content: boxText
                ,disableAutoPan: false
                ,maxWidth: 0
                ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-40, 0)
                ,zIndex: null
                ,boxStyle: { 
                    background: "none",
                    opacity: 0.85
                 }
                ,closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px"
                ,closeBoxURL: ""
                ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
                ,isHidden: true
                ,pane: "floatPane"
                ,enableEventPropagation: false
                ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(10, 10)
            };

            var infobox'.$marker_number.' = new InfoBox(myOptions);
            infobox'.$marker_number.'.open(map, marker'.$marker_number.');
            ';
        }
```

**PHP code that generates Javascript for Google Maps API:**

```
foreach($config['markers'] as $marker) {
            $marker_number++;
            $map_JS .= '
```

/* THIS PART HANDLES THE MOUSEOVER */

```
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker'.$marker_number.', "mouseover", function(event) {
                infobox'.$marker_number.'.show();

                var height = $("#infobox_content").height();
                $("#infobox").css("height", height);

            });
}
```

***The result of the above code is that `$("#infobox").css("height", height)` is only applied to the very first `<div>` created...

Comment: Perform that action when the `div` is created. So bind it to the `mouseover` event or whatever is creating the `div` and then try and execute it.

Comment: Have you subscribed to the mouseover event of the img and created the divs in the handler code ? If so, you should execute your code after the divs have been rendered to the dom.

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: I tried adding the above 2 lines of code in the anonymous function to the event handler of Google Maps V3 API called `google.maps.event.addListener()` but it seems to just update the first of many divs that is created

Comment: Nyxynyxx: IDs must be unique. [See my answer below.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557544/using-jquery-to-select-a-div-that-exists-only-on-mouseover/6557856#6557856) In spite of the numerous recommendations, `.live()` will do nothing to help you here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note that every set of  created has the same id infobox, infobox_content. I can add a number to make them unique but then I will need to change my CSS stylesheet to select infobox1, infobox2, infobox3.... infobox10

IDs ***must*** be unique.

Trying to select by ID when there are multiple on the page will usually only give you the first match.

In your case, you should use a class instead of an ID since they're repeating, and use the class in your CSS for styling.

Beyond that, if you posted the code rendered to the client instead of your server-side code, it may add some clarity as to the best solution.

`.live()` will do *nothing* to help you here unless you're trying to associate event handlers with the new elements.

Comment: Solved it by styling with the same class and assigning each `div` with a unique id. Looks like I have to read up properly on CSS :-/

Answer (score 4):

take a look at live(): http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: `.live()` is *only* for triggering event handlers.

Answer (score 2):

use live()

```
$('#newdivid').live('click',function(){

   //code goes here 

});
```

Live will apply to dynamically applied objects

Comment: How do I target a Google Map API marker? Its when the user mouseover the Google Maps marker that causes the <div> to be visible.

Comment: Doesn't matter when the `div` appears or what causes it to happen. The code littletipz posted should work.

Comment: @littletipz @Michael Mior : Code added, let me know if my code is unclear

Comment: `.live()` is *only* for triggering event handlers. The question isn't about handling events for the new elements.

Answer (score 2):

```
var origHeight;
$("#infobox_content").live("mouseover mouseout", function(event) {
  if ( event.type == "mouseover" ) {
    origHeight = $("#infobox").height();
    $("#infobox").css('height',$("#infobox_content").height());
  } else {
    if(origHeight)
    $("#infobox").css('height',origHeight); 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would check out the the live() function.  http://api.jquery.com/live/.  It's like bind, but you you can attach an event handler to current selection, now and in the future.